# DC Motor control

Tags: motor, dc, dc-motor

I am using a DC 24v scrapped photocopier motor for a table fan.

To save energy, it's ON for 2 seconds and OFF for 3 seconds using MCU.

The fan keeps rotating during the power off state.

Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 5):

What Joe said - a faster time constant would be better, motors fail more quickly if they are speeding up & slowing down like that (we used to get major fan bearing failures on kit which had temperature-switched fans compared with stuff that just ran the fans all the time).

You may also find when it's spinning freely it's generating back-emf which could be feeding back into your circuit, so be aware of that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion John U. I too thought of that. Very nice to hear your practical experience.

Answer (score 4):

What you have there is a crude low-frequency version of [Pulse-Width Modulation (PWM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) control. The normal way to do this accomplishes variable speed control and saves energy by doing the same thing at a much higher switching frequency,  generally around 10 kHz for motor control. The advantage of that switching frequency over your approach is that little to no momentum is lost between each pulse. The motor speed is dependent on the duty cycle of the PWM waveform.

Most MCU timer modules have a function to do this, if it's not explicitly called PWM, look for "Output Compare" in the MCU reference manual.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The high freq. pwm is making noise from the motor which is unpleasant in the quiet room. Is there a way to overcome?

Comment: You could try a switching frequency outside of the human audible range (20 Hz to 20 kHz).